# script tag in html file does not work at all

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a problem when i use *script tag* in any HTML file, for example I want to do photo gallery by using HTML,CSS, and JS language. However the part of script does not do anything!

This the is code, is there any syntax or logic error!

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function imgFunction(){
var bigImg = document.getElementById ("bigImg");
var smallImg= document.getElementById ("thumbnails");
       smallImg.addEventListener("click", function(event){
       if (event.target.tagName=="IMG"){
  bigImg.src=event.target.src;
  
 }
},false);
 
}
window.addEventListener("load",imgFunction,false);
</script>
```

```css
#gallery {
width:600px;
height:500px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:silver;
padding:10px;
}


#bigImg {
width:600px;
height:400px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:white;

}

#bigImg  img 

{
width:600px;
height:400px;
}

#thumbnails {
width:590;
height:100px;
background-color:white;
margin:5px auto;
padding: 5px;

}

#thumbnails  img 

{
width:100px;
height:90px;
display:block;
float:left;
margin:7.6px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Photo Gallery </h1>
<br>

<div id="gallery">

<div id="bigImg">
<img  src="../images/reception.jpg">
</div><!-- end "bigImg" -->

<div id="thumbnails"  >
<img  src="../images/reception.jpg">
<img  src="../images/x-ray.jpg">
<img  src="../images/patient_room.jpg">
<img  src="../images/gym.jpg">
<img  src="../images/dental_clinic.jpg">

</div><!-- end "thumbnails" -->


</div><!-- end "gallery" -->
```

Comment: `bigImg.src=event.target.src;` isn't doing what you think it is. `#bigImg` is a `div`, therefore, it has no `src`. You need to pass `event.target.src` to the `<img>`

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems.

First: You mustn't put `<script>` tags *inside* a script.

Second: You are setting `bigImg.src` but you have `<div id="bigImg">`.

You put the `id` on the wrong element, so you are trying to set the `src` of the div (which is nonsense) instead of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Your script only refers to the `bigImg` which is a `Div` and hence you cannot set the `src` for it. Instead, you need to get the `IMG` tag inside `bigImg`:

```js
function imgFunction(){
  console.log("inside");
var bigImg = document.getElementById ("bigImg");
var smallImg= document.getElementById ("thumbnails");
       smallImg.addEventListener("click", function(event){
         console.log(event.target.tagName)
       if (event.target.tagName=="IMG"){
         console.log(event.target.src);
         var image = document.querySelector('#bigImg img');
  image.src=event.target.src;
  
 }
},false);
 
}
window.addEventListener("load",imgFunction,false);
```

```css
#gallery {
width:600px;
height:500px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:silver;
padding:10px;
}


#bigImg {
width:600px;
height:400px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:white;

}

#bigImg  img 

{
width:600px;
height:400px;
}

#thumbnails {
width:590;
height:100px;
background-color:white;
margin:5px auto;
padding: 5px;

}

#thumbnails  img 

{
width:100px;
height:90px;
display:block;
float:left;
margin:7.6px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Photo Gallery </h1>
<br>

<div id="gallery">

<div id="bigImg">
<img  src="../images/reception.jpg">
</div><!-- end "bigImg" -->

<div id="thumbnails"  >
<img  src="../images/reception.jpg">
<img  src="../images/x-ray.jpg">
<img  src="../images/patient_room.jpg">
<img  src="../images/gym.jpg">
<img  src="../images/dental_clinic.jpg">

</div><!-- end "thumbnails" -->


</div><!-- end "gallery" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `src` to `div` instead of `img`.

Change the `id` of `div` to `bigImgContainer` or any other and set `id` of `img` to `bigImg`

Working snippet :

```css
#gallery {
width:600px;
height:500px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:silver;
padding:10px;
}


#bigImgContainer {
width:600px;
height:400px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:white;

}

#bigImgContainer  img 

{
width:600px;
height:400px;
}

#thumbnails {
width:590;
height:100px;
background-color:white;
margin:5px auto;
padding: 5px;

}

#thumbnails  img 

{
width:100px;
height:90px;
display:block;
float:left;
margin:7.6px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Photo Gallery </h1>
<br>

<div id="gallery">

<div id="bigImgContainer">
<img id="bigImg"  src="http://placehold.it/150?text=Img1">
</div><!-- end "bigImg" -->

<div id="thumbnails"  >
<img  src="http://placehold.it/150?text=Img1">
<img  src="http://placehold.it/150?text=Img2">
<img  src="http://placehold.it/150?text=Img3">
<img  src="http://placehold.it/150?text=Img4">
<img  src="http://placehold.it/150?text=Img5">

</div><!-- end "thumbnails" -->


</div><!-- end "gallery" -->

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function imgFunction(){
var bigImg = document.getElementById ("bigImg");
var smallImg= document.getElementById ("thumbnails");
       smallImg.addEventListener("click", function(event){
       if (event.target.tagName=="IMG"){
  bigImg.src=event.target.src;
  
 }
},false);
 
}
window.addEventListener("load",imgFunction,false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are trying to set src on the div, which is incorrect.
You need to set on the img.

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function imgFunction(){
var bigImg = document.getElementById ("bigImg");
var smallImg= document.getElementById ("thumbnails");
       smallImg.addEventListener("click", function(event){
       if (event.target.tagName=="IMG"){
        document.querySelector("#bigImg img").src=event.target.src;
 }
},false);
 
}
window.addEventListener("load",imgFunction,false);
</script>
```

```css
#gallery {
width:600px;
height:500px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:silver;
padding:10px;
}


#bigImg {
width:600px;
height:400px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:white;

}

#bigImg  img 

{
width:600px;
height:400px;
}

#thumbnails {
width:590;
height:100px;
background-color:white;
margin:5px auto;
padding: 5px;

}

#thumbnails  img 

{
width:100px;
height:90px;
display:block;
float:left;
margin:7.6px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Photo Gallery </h1>
<br>

<div id="gallery">

<div id="bigImg">
<img  src="../images/reception.jpg">
</div><!-- end "bigImg" -->

<div id="thumbnails"  >
<img  src="../images/reception.jpg">
<img  src="../images/x-ray.jpg">
<img  src="../images/patient_room.jpg">
<img  src="../images/gym.jpg">
<img  src="../images/dental_clinic.jpg">

</div><!-- end "thumbnails" -->


</div><!-- end "gallery" -->
```